# Running multiple instances of Sunspot solr server for running cucumber tests using parallel_tests gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, sunspot-rails

I am using [parallel_tests gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) for running my cucumber features in parallel. 
While i am trying to run the cukes, i am getting

```
Sunspot::Solr::Server::AlreadyRunningError
```

but the process is continuing and only one firefox window is running.

My machine is having two CPUs and i guess the second one is trying to start the sunspot server after the first one is already started it.

The issue i am afraid of though is, i may not using the power of parallel_tests with only one firefox window running.

Can a single sunspot server can serve all the ports? For me only one firefox window is being opened and the cukes are running only for one process. Rarely, there are two sunspot servers running and at the time i can see two browser windows being opened and all the cukes are being run.

Is there anyway to run two sunspot instances?

Am i missing anything here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is apparently solved by a different conversation, listed at https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/issues/176